# xslt transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am developing an application were I need to transform XML documents that look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<!DOCTYPE markables SYSTEM "markables.dtd">
<markables>
<markable id="markable_1" mmax_level="coref" span="word_1..word_4"> </markable>
<markable id="markable_2" mmax_level="coref" span="word_6..word_7"> </markable>
<markable id="markable_3" mmax_level="coref" span="word_10..word_24"> </markable>
</markables>
```

Using a XSLT stylesheet. I would like the result of the transformation to be (in this case) `word_1 word_6 word_10` and this is the XSL I am using:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>

<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="markable">
  <html>
  <body>
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@span"/></td>
    </tr>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is `word_1..word_4 word_6..word_7 word_10..word_24`. What do I have to change in the XSLT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an XSLT function, namely `fn:substring-before(@span, '..')`